# unable to sort java array in descending order in two steps : first from index 0 to 12, second from index 13 to 24

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

Sorry, it may be a dumb question, but I'm a total a beginner :
When I try to execute the following program, it compiles, but I get the following error:

> "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:
>   -1    at Numbers.main(Numbers.java:6)"

Can someone help?

```
 public class Numbers {

    public static void main (String[] args) {

            int [] harry = new int [25];
            for (int i = 0, n = 12; i < harry.length; i++, n--) {
                if (i % 2 > 0) {
                    harry[n] = i;
                }
            } 
            for (int j = 0, m = 25; j < harry.length; j++, m--) {
                if (j % 2 == 0) {
                    harry[m] = j;
                }
            }

            for (int k = 0; k < harry.length; k++) {
                System.out.println(harry[k]);
            }
     }
  }
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but changing `m = 25` to `m = harry.length-1` will fix at least the first issue with your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides having to initialize `m` to `harry.length - 1` (since 25 is out of bounds), you should only decrement `n` and `m` when you use them (i.e. when you assign a value to the `harry` array):

```
int [] harry = new int [25];
for (int i = 0, n = 12; i < harry.length; i++) {
    if (i % 2 > 0) {
        harry[n] = i;
        n--;
    }
} 
for (int j = 0, m = harry.length - 1; j < harry.length; j++) {
    if (j % 2 == 0) {
        harry[m] = j;
        m--;
    }
}
```

Otherwise, `n` will become negative before the first loop is done, and `m` will become too small.

Answer (score 0):

You have this kind of runtime exception because you try to get harry[-1], but it's impossible. You will also see this exception in the second for, because you set m = 25, but indexces of your array are from 0 to 24.
Set n=harry.length-1 and m = harry.length-1, then your program will work.

Answer (score 0):

On the following line,

```
 for (int j = 0, m = 25; j < harry.length; j++, m--) {
```

m = 25, it should be 25-1, otherwise it will throw index out of bound exception

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand everything but I believe if you do this your code should work perfectly:

Use `if (i % 2 > 0 && n >= 0)`  instead of `if (i % 2 > 0)`

and use `if (j % 2 == 0 && m<=24)` instead of `if (j % 2 == 0)`

Hope this helps.